# Samsung 27 inch 1920x1080 won't use the right resolution on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, laptop, resolution, vga

My laptop runs on Windows 7 Professional (VGA+Display Port but not HDMI). I just bought a new external monitor Samsung 27" 1920x1080 but the maximum resolution which is available in the screen resolution selection dialog box is 1600x1200. Connection between the laptop and the monitor is VGA-to-VGA. 
To make sure that the new monitor was okay I connected another laptop that does have an HDMI output and it worked just fine. 
I then detached the HDMI cable from the second laptop and connected, through VGA cable, the monitor to my laptop. This time it displayed at 1920x1080 and I thought that the problem was gone.
Unfortunately upon restarting the monitor / laptop, the new resolution 1920x1080 disappeared and 1600x1200 is the maximum available.

Drivers are up-to-date.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Interesting because I saw a similar problem a couple of months back where a 24" 1920x1200 monitor refused to work above 1024x768 no matter what cable we used. This was using an NVidia card. But when connected to my laptop it works fine in full resolution. I assumed it was an NVidia driver problem.

Comment: Probably the simplest solution would be to not use VGA, use DP. VGA doesn't carry the screen's ID codes well on newer devices.

Comment: My monitor does not have DP only HDMI but my laptop does not have HDMI. I am stuck...any clue?